# Angularjs fallback, hide for none javascript users

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, fallback

I know about the script-tag for adding content that none javascript users can read.

What is the best way to hide html blocks that is created for angularjs?

**Example:**

```
<div>
{{this_code_is_converted_to_angular_js_code_when_javascript_is_active}}
</div>
```

The line above is not that beautiful for a none javascript user. What is the best way to remove it if the user is not using javascript?

Comment: are you using the `ng-view` directive? If i'm looking at source in developer tools for chrome it doesn't look like you are. You have everything inside the same html file. You should make a SPA application where Angular switches out your views.

Comment: No I'm just dumping it in so far. Maybe a "SPA"-thing would be better. I'm quite new to Angularjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to hide elements you can use ng-cloak
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Be aware that your page will not start rendering before angular has parsed your whole application if present on the body tag. It is advised to use on as small portions as possible, for continuous rendering. @JensTörnell

Comment: Please note that in order for this solution to work, you have to manually add ng-cloak css rules for your site, because by default they are also generated by javascript, and therefore the ng-cloak elements are still visible when JS is disabled.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `<noscript>` tag to display content when *JavaScript* is not enabled.

Also the `main.html` file should not have any `{{content}}` tags, instead you should have sub views which are loaded into the `<div ng-view=""></div>`

This way if *JavaScript* is not enabled, only content in the `noscript` tag will be displayed because the `ng-view div` is empty, as *AngularJS* is *JavaScript* and will never insert anything into the `ng-view div`.

[Example HTML](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div ng-view></div>
  <noscript>Enable JavaScript to view this web page.</noscript>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options...

Since you specifically don't want to display HTML block for NON-Angular (non-javascript), then you should ONLY place that HTML code within either:

- use `ngBindTemplate` (preferred):

  > ```
  > <script>
  >   function Ctrl($scope) {
  >     $scope.salutation = 'Hello';
  >     $scope.name = 'World';
  >   }
  > </script>
  > <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  >  Salutation: <input type="text" ng-model="salutation"><br>
  >  Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"><br>
  >  <pre ng-bind-template="{{salutation}} {{name}}!"></pre>
  > </div>
  > ```
- or... `ngBind`:

  > ```
  > <script>
  >   function Ctrl($scope) {
  >     $scope.name = 'Whirled';
  >   }
  > </script>
  > <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  >   Enter name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"><br>
  >   Hello <span ng-bind="name"></span>!
  > </div>
  > ```

  The main difference being that "...unlike `ngBind`, the `ngBindTemplate` can contain multiple `{{ }}` expressions. This directive is needed since some HTML elements (such as `TITLE` and `OPTION`) cannot contain `SPAN` elements.": https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindTemplate

  ### In your specific example/question:

  ```
   <div ng-bind="hide-this-when-no-js">
     {{this_code_is_converted_to_angular_js_code_when_javascript_is_active}}
   </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but if you don't want to display `{{ }}` marks in your page when javascript is not enabled you should try using [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) and/or [ng-bind-template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindTemplate) instead.